# Why using "in" preposition in the case?

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence:

> James made a hole in the bottom of a bucket.

Why using *in* preposition, while not talking about *inside* of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *in* has many more meanings than *inside of*. (Whoever told you that *in* means *inside of* only told you half of the story. Check that – only told you about a tenth of the story!)

In their first definition of *in*, [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/in_2) lists several examples, including these:

> Put the milk back in the fridge.
>   Is Mark still in bed?
>   I got stuck in a traffic jam for half an hour.
>   They live in a charming old cottage.
>   I've got a pain in my back.
>   How much is that coat on display in the window (= *in the space behind the window of the shop*)?
>   **I've got something in (= *on the surface of*) my eye.**

It's that last one that solves your mystery: the word *in* can be used to mean *on the surface of*. That's why we can say things like:

> The iceberg cut a gash in the hull of the ship.
>   That pool table has a tear in the felt – no wonder they're only asking fifty dollars for it.
>   I just slipped in the mud; now I have a stain on my sleeve and a rip in my pants.
>   Dear Eliza, there's a hole in the bucket.